# cffunction/cfargument pass unsigned int32

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm working on building a function that will convert an unsigned int32 to an ipv4 address and it all works great until I test with the upper half of the range.

```
<cffunction name="Int32ToIPv4" returntype="string" output="false" access="public" hint="returns IPv4 address for int32 number">
    <cfargument name="nInt32" type="numeric" required="yes" hint="int32 to convert to ipv4 address">

    <cfreturn
        bitAnd((arguments.nInt32 / 16777216), 255) & "."
        & bitAnd((arguments.nInt32 / 65536), 255) & "."
        & bitAnd((arguments.nInt32 / 256), 255) & "."
        & bitAnd(arguments.nInt32, 255)
    >
</cffunction>
```

ColdFusion appears to interpret type="numeric" to be a **signed** 32-bit integer.

This example works:

```
Int32ToIPv4(nInt32 = 1181772947) = #Int32ToIPv4(nInt32 = 1181772947)# (expected value = 70.112.108.147)<br>
```

This example fails:

```
Int32ToIPv4(nInt32 = 3401190660) = #Int32ToIPv4(nInt32 = 3401190660)# (expected value = 202.186.13.4)<br>
```

The error message is: "Cannot convert the value 3.40119066E9 to an integer because it cannot fit inside an integer."

Will I have to pass this number in as a string and convert it to a Java unsigned int before using it?

I'll want to do something similar with ipv6 addresses (unsigned 128-bit integer) at some point.  Any advice for this type of data-type would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually [bitAnd()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/bitand.html) imposing the 32 bit integer limitation, not cfargument.

Interestingly, if you check each calculation separately, the first three (3) work fine. Due to the division, the values passed into `bitAnd()` are actually small enough to fit inside an INT. However, the last one uses the raw value which is obviously too big, and that is what causes the error with this specific number.

```
 bitAnd(  (3401190660 / 16777216), 255 )  // Actual => 202.7267611032, 255
 bitAnd(  (3401190660 / 65536), 255 ) // Actual => 51898.05084233, 255
 bitAnd(  (3401190660 / 256), 255 )  // Actual =>13285901.0156, 255
 bitAnd(3401190660, 255) // Too big!
```

Since most of the relevant math functions in CF are limited to 32 bit integers, I am not sure if (or how simply) it can be done with CF alone. Assuming you are using Java 8+, you also have access to the new unsigned methods like [Integer.parseUnsignedInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-).

Personally I think this would be a great learning exercise. However, unless you are very familiar with the details of signed versus unsigned and how it relates to IP4 and IP6 addresses, you might just want to use an existing java library to avoid common pitfalls. Such as [Guava's InetAdress](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html):

```
// IP4
input = 3401190660;
uint = createObject("java", "java.lang.Integer").parseUnsignedInt(input);
inet = createObject("Java", "com.google.common.net.InetAddresses");
result = inet.fromInteger(uint).getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @leigh.  I did come up with a native Java only solution which I will post for review/info but I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: @Scott - Heh... I think we saw the same thread on SO. I gave it a quick (unsuccessful) whirl before my coffee kicked in, but must have missed something. Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 2):

I did come up with a native Java solution that involved passing in an unsigned 32-bit int.  So, @Leigh is correct about cfargument working properly.

```
<cffunction name="UInt32ToIPv4" returntype="string" output="no" access="public" hint="returns IPv4 address for uint32 number">
    <cfargument name="nUInt32" type="numeric" required="yes" hint="uint32 to convert to ipv4 address">

    <cfset local['JavaLangInteger'] = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Integer")>
    <cfset local['JavaMathBigInteger'] = CreateObject("java", "java.math.BigInteger")>
    <cfset local['JavaNetInetAddress'] = CreateObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>

    <cfif arguments.nUInt32 EQ 0>
        <cfreturn "">
    </cfif>

    <cftry>
        <cfset local['vcIPv4'] = local.JavaNetInetAddress.getByAddress(local.JavaMathBigInteger.valueOf(local.JavaLangInteger.parseUnsignedInt(arguments.nUInt32)).toByteArray())>
        <cfreturn reReplace(local.vcIPv4, "[^0-9\.]", "", "all")>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfreturn "">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

Let me know if there are any problems with this solution as I think that I will use it instead of a public java library.

I have written functions for ipv6 to handle the conversions (unsigned 128-bit int to/from ipv6).  Not sure that there is an interest in those functions.  If there is, I'll create separate questions/answers with that code.

Comment: Nice! Did you use something similar for ip6?  (Minor side note, just use `local.vcIPv4.getHostAddress()` to return the address instead of using `reReplace()` on an object).

Comment: @Leigh, Thanks.  I wouldn't call it similar as there are several differences.  128 bit unsigned it for the underlying ipv6 number, I used java.net.Inet6Address and java.math.BigInteger, but the library had two problems.  If the number was too small, it would fail.  Too large and the signed problem again.

Comment: @Leigh, in regards to the reReplace(), my first attempts to just return the string would include a leading "/".  I'll check the code again to see if that is still the case and let you know.

Comment: @Leigh, confirmed using local.vcIPv4.getHostAddress() does return the IP address without the leading "/".  local.JavaNetInetAddress.getByAddress() does return a leading "/".  Should have known that the return is a Java object vs. a string.  Going to have to clean up this code a little more...

Comment: Yes, CF makes it easy to overlook. It probably falls back to `Object.toString()`, which looks like it is a concatenation of host name (if resolved) +"/"+ ip address. I would be curious to see the ipv6 version when you are done with it :)

Comment: After working on the ipv6 code that became really obvious.  ColdFusion does a lot of data translating work for us and can really simplify these tasks.  Here is a link to the ipv6 version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203963/coldfusion-128-bit-unsigned-int-to-ipv6